# 2 python scripts communicating with arduino on the same port

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am kind of new to programming using python, so I hope u can help me.what I need is to use 2 python scripts to communicate with arduino on the same port, so I want to run the first script and it sends data via serial, then I stop the first one and run the second script, to compleat the communication, but when I run the second script, the serial communication stops and nothing is sent from the second one. Can u help me solve this issue please??

Comment: Is the first script closing the port when it is done with it? Post some code please

Comment: What issue? You have no code in your question.  No one can speculate why it isn't working.  Code is *required* to use the `arduino` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use to different script to work on the same port.
You don't require 2 separate scripts to make your work done
you can do it by the single script also
eg:-

```
import serial
MyPort = serial.Serial('<Your Serial Port name>',9600)
MyPort.write(b'send your data') 
MyPort.close()
MyPort.open()
data = MyPort.readline()
print(data)
ser.close()
```

and on to your Board side like Arduino:-

```
int incomingdata = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    incomingdata = Serial.read(); 
    Serial.print(" I received:");
    Serial.println(incomingdata);
}
```

for installing the library:- `python -m pip install pyserial`

by this, you can do both incoming and outgoing at a time and you don't need 2 different scripts to run
THANK YOU